# How to add text box and command button in excel user form during run time?

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I want to add n number of text box and one command button during run time of the user form in excel - vba .
While the number 'n' , i am getting through a cell value .
I want to store the data entered ( in the dynamically  during run time created text box when the user clicks on Submit button that is also run time created )
in excel sheet  .

```
For i = 1 To ssheet.Cells(2, 2).Value
        Set txtB1 = Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")

        With txtB1
            .Name = "d" & i
            .Height = 25
            .Width = 150
            .Left = 105
            .Top = 20 + 10 * i * 4
        End With


Set cCont = Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1", "Button", True)

    With cCont
        .Caption = "Submit"
        .Top = 60 + 10 * ssheet.Cells(2, 2).Value * 4
        .Left = 105

    End With
```

Here i am able to display as required but unable to trigger the users button click and store values in excel sheet .

Comment: You want to store the data from cell into the textboxes when the command button is clicked?

Comment: I want to store the data entered in textboxes by user into cells when command button is clicked .

Comment: Actually my requirement is to store N number of datas (strings ) into cells using user form.i am getting N from Cell(2,2).value .

Comment: 1.Don't know syntax how to add a command _click code for a button generated during runtime.
2.And assign values to cells from run time generated text boxes .

I know above for elements added before runtime .

Comment: I can get why you would want to create textboxes in runtime but do you really need to add the button on runtime? If the button is already there on the userform, it would be much easier (you can hide the button initially and show it only if you have >1 text box)

Comment: Since the location of the button has to vary corresponding to number of text boxes .

Comment: Yes i will hide the button . Can you help me regrading storing data from run time text box to cells.

Comment: that is ok ... you can place the button at the bottom of all your text boxes. its easy to get the location info

Comment: Yes i will hide the button . Can you help me regrading storing data from run time text box to cells. And how to locate the button to end .Thanks !

Comment: I have added a sample solution for your issue. Hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks! Will try and inform if any issue arises .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So create a userform and add the command button in design time like below

[image]

Add the following code in the user form

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    For i = 1 To ssheet.Cells(2, 2).Value
        ssheet.Cells(i, 5).Value = Controls("d" & i).Value
    Next i
    Unload UserForm1
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    If ssheet.Cells(2, 2).Value > 0 Then
        For i = 1 To ssheet.Cells(2, 2).Value
            Set txtB1 = Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")
            With txtB1
                .Name = "d" & i
                .Height = 25
                .Width = 150
                .Left = 10
                .Top = 30 * (i - 1) + 5
            End With
        Next i

        With CommandButton1
            .Caption = "Submit"
            .Top = 30 * (i - 1) + 5
            .Left = 10
        End With

        With Me
            .Width = 200
            .Height = 200
            .ScrollTop = 0
            .KeepScrollBarsVisible = fmScrollBarsVertical
            .ScrollBars = fmScrollBarsVertical
            .ScrollHeight = 30 * i + 5
        End With
    Else
        CommandButton1.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

You can then call the userform from workbook module

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

When you load the form, the text boxes will be created and aligned based on B2 cell's value

[image]